# byte array to file path

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side, .net-6.0

I have a byte[] image in a DB.  I'm using Radzen components, specifically the radzenImage component that only supports a Path= to the image.

This code compiles and runs but the image is not rendered.  How would I create a localized in-memory **path**  of the data image? Here's what I have so far.

```
<RadzenImage Path=getImage(product.ThumbNailPhoto) style="width: 40px; height: 40px; border-radius: 8px;" />

public string GetImage(byte[]? image)
    {
        if (image != null)
        {
            return $"data:image/png;base64, {Convert.ToBase64String(image)}";
        }
        else
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

Can getImage return an in-memory file path to the base64 image? If so, how?